# A name/reference for small top-level clusters in hierarchical clustering

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

When you perform hierarchical clustering, often some outliers "cluster out" at the top level into tiny small-size clusters. I need to discuss this effect in my paper, and I'm not sure how to call it.

For example, in the dendrogram below, the top three levels of hierarchical clustering are size-1 and size-2 clusters (of course filled with outliers).

[image]